# firefox in centos set csp header not effective

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, content-security-policy, selenium-firefoxdriver

I try to join the csp header for the response of each request accessed by firefox through the proxy, but no csp report send, and try to do same thing in mac firefox(same code), the program runs without problems and i recv csp report,so i think it may be problem of firefox in centos

this is my environment, install firefox by yum, code use selenium operate firefox and use browsermob to add csp header in response, in code result csp header already add in response,firefox in headless mode.

```
centos 7
firefox.x86_64                            68.5.0-2.el7.centos     @update
firefox.i686                              68.5.0-2.el7.centos     update
firefox-noscript.noarch                   11.0.3-3.el7            epel
firefox-pkcs11-loader.x86_64              3.13.4-1.el7            epel
```

this is my csp rule

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: script-src 'none'; style-src 'none'; img-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; connect-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; child-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; worker-src 'none'; worker-src 'none'; worker-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'; manifest-src 'none'; report-uri http://www.test.com
```

I use this to recv csp report and use this report to create csp rule for web

Is there any way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update firefox version, test v74.0 work well

yum version to old, install by this in centos 7

```
cd /usr/local
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/74.0/linux-x86_64/zh-CN/firefox-74.0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf firefox-74.0.tar.bz2
yum -y install gtk3-devel
yum install libXt*
ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```